# Django inline_formset - ensure at least one item selected

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an inlineformset_factory which where I need 'result' selected for at least one of the submitted forms:

These are my forms:

```
class CBVQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id','question','image','time','weight','company','tags','category','author']
        widgets = {'id': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'time' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control quiz-search-box'}),
                   'weight' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control quiz-search-box'}),
                   'company' : forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'author' : forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'tags' : TagWidget(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean_tags(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['tags']
        for d in data:
            d = d.replace('[','').replace(']','')
        return data


class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude = ['user_answer']
        fields = ['result','question','answer']
        widgets = {
            'result' : forms.CheckboxInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class' : 'right_answer'
                }
            ),
            'question' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'answer' : forms.Textarea(
                attrs = {
                    'class' : 'form-control quiz-search-box',
                    'required' : '',
                    'rows' : 3,
                }
            ),

        }

AnswerFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Question,
    Answer,
    form=AnswerForm,
    extra=0,
    can_delete = True,
    can_order = False,
    max_num=4,
    min_num=1
)
```

I'm forcing the first inline form to have result set to true using JQuery, and then ensuring if another result is selected, again using JQuery to keep it to just one selected, like so:

```
$('#qform').on('change', 'input.right_answer', function() {
    $('input.right_answer').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set the first check box to checked
    {% if not edit %}
    $('#id_answer_set-0-result').prop("checked", "checked")
    {% endif %}
})
```

The problem is, if a formset is deleted when it is selected as the right answer, I cannot capture it and ensure something else is checked.

I've tried a number of things, like:

```
$( "#qform" ).submit(function( event ) {
    checked = $("input.right_answer:checked").length;
    if (checked == 0) {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

and

```
$('#answerTable').bind('rowAddOrRemove', function(event){
    checked = $("input.right_answer:checked").length;
    if (checked == 0) {
        $('#qform').find('input.right_answer:first', function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", "checked")
        })
    }
});
```

I cannot get anything to work and help would be greatly appreciated.

Extract from form:

```
<form  id= "qform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >   {% csrf_token %}
...
            <table class="table" id="answerTable">
                {{ answers.management_form }}
                {% for form in answers %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
</form>
```

Please note, since I'm using Django inlineformset, if the formset was passed from the backend, when deleted it is only hidden by JavaScript and then deleted in the backend.

Comment: Can you make a demo link to demonstrate the issue?
Edit: Are you able to 'validate' these conditions on serverside (when javascript is disabled)?

Comment: @art06 how would you suggest validating within the backend?  I'm using a Class Based View

Comment: You can't depend fully upon js based validation. Normally, django automatically validates all form data as per the given field attributes. However, when using a formset, you might need to make extra measures that all required conditions are met before saving the data into DB. btw, could you post the code that deletes the rows?